# preg_match not working properly

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have some data and i want to find out value of it so i try preg_match function it can be easy to finding values i try the the following code to obtain values but i think there is some problem in my code because i am getting value of $a but i try everything to finding value of $a1 here is m sample code

```
$data=Date:29-05-2016 11:36 - Mo:919530489323 - pdd:9339 - lpm:78JIOP-
pas:sami  
preg_match('#Date:(.*?) (.*?) - Mo:91(.*?) - pdd:(.*?) -
lpm:(.*?) - pas:(.*?)#',$data,$matches);  
$a=$matches[3];
 $a1=$matches[6];
```

now what i do to get value of $a1 or what is right code for it

Comment: It means No matches .... `print_r` and see

Comment: Provide reproducible code. Between `pdd` and `lpm` there is no new line in the string.. Also I'd write a stricter regex than `.*?`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your last word for `regex` to match entire word. Currently it returns blank(if you have `print_r` matches array).

use `regex` as follow:

```
preg_match('#Date:(.*?) (.*?) - Mo:91(.*?) - pdd:(.*?) - lpm:(.*?) - pas:(.*)#',$data,$matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your last bracket is using [laziness mark](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) with wildcard, it will match nothing except other rules require it to. There is no other rules to specify the end of the overall match, so the last part `sami` is simply skipped by your regular expression. You can examine this:

```
<?php

$data="Date:29-05-2016 11:36 - Mo:919530489323 - pdd:9339 - lpm:78JIOP - pas:sami";
preg_match('#Date:(.*?) (.*?) - Mo:91(.*?) - pdd:(.*?) - lpm:(.*?) - pas:(.*?)#',$data,$matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Which output this:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(70) "Date:29-05-2016 11:36 - Mo:919530489323 - pdd:9339 - lpm:78JIOP - pas:"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "29-05-2016"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "11:36"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "9530489323"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "9339"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "78JIOP"
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Notice the overall matching string (`$matches[0]`) value actually stops at the last `:`. that's why you have an empty string in `$matches[6]`.

Chainging the regular expression will fix the issue:

```
<?php

$data="Date:29-05-2016 11:36 - Mo:919530489323 - pdd:9339 - lpm:78JIOP - pas:sami";
preg_match('#^Date:(.*?) (.*?) - Mo:91(.*?) - pdd:(.*?) - lpm:(.*?) - pas:(.*?)$#',$data,$matches);         

var_dump($matches);
```

Notice the `^` and `$` I've added. They will match "the beginning of string" and "the end of string". So the string from the last `:` to the end of whole input string will be included. Which output this:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(74) "Date:29-05-2016 11:36 - Mo:919530489323 - pdd:9339 - lpm:78JIOP - pas:sami"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "29-05-2016"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "11:36"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "9530489323"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "9339"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "78JIOP"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "sami"
}
```